# Do Champions show in Battle in Total War: Rome 2?

Tags: rome-2-total-war

I bought recently the Emperor Edition of Total War: Rome 2.

After playing a little bit with Sparta I saw that I could recruit a Champion. So I went on and recruited **Leonidas** to train my troops.

And I was so excited to be able to fight the next battle but when I went into battle I tried to find some model of him in the army or see him assigned to some special unit but nothing. He was nowhere.

So my question is: Did I do something wrong or Champions serve only as Agents and don't appear in Battles?

If they don't are there any mods that allow that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No -- Champions, Spys and Dignitaries do not appear on the battlefield. They are only there to perform agents actions and / or give their acquired bonuses to your army.